# Inexplicable Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

This is my Java.

When I try to run it gives me the Null Pointer Exception

at the following line:

**back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()**

I debugged and indeed the Button "back" is null.

But Why?

**EDIT**

**It runs on a Gingerbread phone, not on a Nexus 7**

```
public class QuotesActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface {
private String url2;
public static ArrayList<Stock> lt;
public static ArrayList<Stock> favQ;
public MyAdapter myAdap;
public Intent intent;
public ListView lv;
public FavManager fm;
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.search);


    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();

    // request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    request.setGender(AdRequest.Gender.MALE);
    boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
    if (tabletSize) {
        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "dgfdfgdfgdfgd");
    } else {
        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "sfsdfsdfsdfsfs");
    }

    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad);

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(request);

    lt = new ArrayList<Stock>();
    favQ = new ArrayList<Stock>();
    fm = new FavManager(getApplicationContext());
    favQ.clear();
    favQ.addAll(fm.ritiraFav());
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
    lt.clear();
    // ////////////
    try {
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.markets3);

        if (in != null) {
            InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);
            String str;
            String str1 = null;
            String str2 = null;
            boolean flag = true;
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (flag) {
                    str1 = str;
                    flag = false;
                } else {
                    str2 = str;
                    lt.add(new Stock(str1, str2, "0", "0"));
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            in.close();
        }
    }

    catch (Throwable t) {
        // Log.e("", "Exception: " + t.toString());
    }
    // ///////
    Collections.sort(lt, new Comparator<Stock>() {
        public int compare(Stock s1, Stock s2) {
            return s1.nome.compareToIgnoreCase(s2.nome);
        }
    });
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    Button favourites = (Button) findViewById(R.id.favoritesbtn);
    favourites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuotesActivity.this,
                    QuotesActivityFavourites.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFinish);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();
        }
    });
```

This is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RequestFocusLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_box"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lista"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="All stocks on US Markets"
            android:textSize="15dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nome"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/googsearch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/actionsearch"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="7dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/View"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Symbol"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prezzo"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/freccia"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cambiamento"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Change %"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="8dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/aggiorna"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Click to\nupdate"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_box"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/preferencebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/actionsettings"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="Preferences\n&amp;\nHelp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favoritesbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ratingfavorite"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="Your\nPortfolio"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonFinish"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/contentundo"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="Return"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="8sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the LogCat:

```
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.marketsinyourpocket/com.marketsinyourpocket.QuotesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at com.marketsinyourpocket.QuotesActivity.onCreate(QuotesActivity.java:136)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-17 19:18:41.372: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: I can't tell with the way its formatted but is `Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFinish);` inside `onCreate()`?

Comment: put this line in oncreate `Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFinish);`

Comment: @codeMagic thanks, but why not? It is done all the time...

Comment: @codeMagic it is inside onCreate()...

Comment: Oh ok, miscommunication.

Comment: If your tags are correct in your actual xml then I would try cleaning. "Project --> Clean..." and/or restarting Eclipse, if that's what you're using, because everything else seems to be ok

Comment: Don't understand why people vote this down. An app I have (BpmDj) also has this type of spurious errors, but _only_ on nexus devices. So despite the fact that yes, maybe he should check whether findViewById returned null, the question still is why nexus devices can return null when the xml contains the correct tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFinish);
```

Does not necessarily return a button. It will return the button if it can find said button. Otherwise you're getting a null reference, which will cause the error on the very next line.

Check that the button does exist, and with the ID you passed to the `findViewById` method. If that's the method you really intend on using to fetch the button.

Comment: `<Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonFinish"` its there in xml

Comment: @LisaAnne if you're still getting a null pointer exception, my point stands - check why the button is null at that moment, because your code is otherwise right.

Comment: @Renan I do not see how... you can see the Button in the XML

Comment: Being in the XML is one thing, being in the activity that you're manipulating in your code is another entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid XML - your Root Element is a `RelativeLayout` but the ending tag is `</LinearLayout>`. Your button resource may not be compiled into your app yet as a result.

In your latest XML, there are 4 opening `<LinearLayout>` tags and only 3 closing ones.

Comment: @Lisa Anne - my point still stands, there are 4 opening <LinearLayout> tags and only 3 closing LinearLayout tags

Answer (score 1):

After a couple edits, I still can't tell if what you pasted is your entire XML file, so I'm going to work on the assumption that it is.

Your tags are mismatched. I took your layout and stripped the fluff to show the structure:

```
<LinearLayout>                  // L1 Open
    <RelativeLayout/>           // R1 
    <LinearLayout>              // L2 Open
        <RelativeLayout>        // R2 Open
            <TextView/>         
        </RelativeLayout>       // R2 Close
        <LinearLayout>          // L3 Open
            <TextView/>
            <Button/>
            <View/>
            <TextView/>
            <TextView/>
            <TextView/>
            <TextView/>
            <TextView/>
        </LinearLayout>         // L3 Close
    </LinearLayout>             // L2 Close
    <ListView/>
    <LinearLayout>              // L4 Open
        <LinearLayout/>         // L5
        <RelativeLayout>        // R3 Open
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
        </RelativeLayout>       // R3 Close
    </LinearLayout>             // L4 Close
                                // No L1 Close!
```

You need another closing `</LinearLayout>` tag. Otherwise, it will mess up the parsing and you will get some strange results.

If what you pasted is **not**, in fact, your entire XML file, then I'd strongly suggest in the future that you paste the whole thing from the start. It will eliminate some of the guesswork and frustration.

Either way, I'd strongly recommend a `Build->Clean`. Well, I'd recommend that after changing *anything* in the `/res` folder, but doubly if you have a strange null pointer or class cast exception showing up.